# C# Unity - Preventing The Player From Standing on a Certain Terrain Texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, terrain

I am wondering how to prevent the player from walking on a certain texture on the Unity terrain. I have made the script that detects on which texture the player is standing on. For the movement I use the rigidbody velocity so I don't have problems with colliders. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

First, create the global variable lastPos:

```
Vector3 lastPos;
```

Then set it to the players current position on Start:

```
void Start() {
  lastPos = player.gameObject.transform.position;
}
```

Then in Update, set the lastPos variable to the players current position. Next, use an if statement to check if the player is on an invalid texture. If the player is on an invalid texture, set it's position back to lastPos:

```
void Update() {
  if (playerOnInvalidTexture) {
    player.gameObject.transform.position = lastPos;
  }
  lastPos = player.gameObject.transform.position;
}
```

Essentially this places the player at a valid position when on an invalid texture.

Comment: Doesn't work... It just glitches a bit. Wait, shouldn't I first check then set the lastPost ?

Comment: yea that did the job, had to set the lastPos after the check, thanks :D

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, updating answer to reflect this*. You are welcome, good luck!!